# How do I use variables or functions to remember the input from a prompt in Powershell?

Tags: function, loops, scripting, powershell, move

I need to move files from one folder to another. I need to be able to choose how many files that shall be moved, and then it shall loop until it there's no more files in the source folder. Between the loops, it needs to take a break. I might be way off.
So far I got a script like this:

```
    $FileCount = (ls $env:C:\users\jenstmar\desktop\*.*).count


Function Source {gci -path (Read-Host -Prompt 'Set Source') -exclude PowerFlyt |}
Function FileNumber {Get-Random -Count 4 (Read-Host -Prompt 'Set number of files to move a time') |}
Function Destination {mi -Destination (Read-Host -Prompt 'Set Destination') -exclude PowerFlyt.ps1 |}



do 
{
 Source |
 FileNumber |
 Destination |
    sleep -sec 20; .\PowerFlyt.ps1 
}
while($FileCount -gt 0)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a question. Did you try your script? What problem exactly did you get?

Comment: The question was in the title. I've now fixed the problem.

Comment: Read-Host -prompt "What is it going to be? (Yes/no)"
You then have to filter if string is Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, functions are not like macros or something which are inlined in the code. Functions are called and they return valued to the pipeline.

So your usage like

```
Source |
 FileNumber |
 Destination |
```

and defining functions like

Function Source {gci -path (Read-Host -Prompt 'Set Source') -exclude PowerFlyt |}

will not work. Change the functions without those trailing pipes (`|`).

To pass the variable from read-host, save the read values in variables:

```
Function Source {
$script:source = read-host "set source"
gci -path $source -exclude PowerFlyt
}
```

You can now access `$script:source` in other functions in the script. Do the same for any other variable.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The end result was like this:

```
$Source = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Set Source') 
$FileNumbers = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Set number of files to move a time')
$Destination = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Set Destination') 

do 
{
$FileCount = (ls $Source).count 
gci -path $Source -exclude <NameOfScript.ps1> |
Get-Random -Count $FileNumbers | 
mi -Destination $Destination 
sleep -sec 5; 
}
while ($FileCount -gt 1)
```

Thanks for your help and time.